# How to get user response from Facebook messenger chatbot?

Tags: facebook, chatbot, messenger

I am building new chatbot for survey. In this case, how do I get the user's answer for the last asked question and how to store the answer for corresponding question in DB.

Example conversation

`User: Get start
Bot: Hi! Welcome to the survey
Bot: What is your job profile
User: I am software engineer.`

Here, I want to store the answer "I am a software engineer" for the question "Job profile". How to store these values?

Comment: You get the value from Facebook. You just store it. I don't understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

You get the user response directly on your message handler function which you have written in your application. I am sure there must be message handler app which is hooked with FB messenger to communicate between your chatbot logic and FB messenger. Within that app, you must handle the user responses to be saved into your data store.